# VkApi, Python. Не работает черный список у бота

Tags: vkontakte-api, list, if, условия

Имеется страничный бот со следующим кодом:

```
ignore_list = ['id человека']
while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():

            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                from_id = event.user_id
                msg_text = event.text.lower()
                message_id = event.message_id

                if from_id not in ignore_list: #проверка на присутствие в чс
                    if event.from_chat:
                        peer_id = event.peer_id
                        chat_id = event.chat_id
                        user_name = session.method('users.get', {
                            'user_ids': from_id
                        })
                        print(f' {from_id}: {msg_text}')

                        if msg_text == '1':
                            sender_chat(206, 'ответ 1')
                        if msg_text == '2':
                            sender_chat(206, 'ответ 2')

                elif from_id in ignore_list: #или просто else: если в чс
                    sender_chat(206, 'ты в чс ')
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Условие почему-то не работает или работает не корректно. Пользователю в чс бот по прежнему предоставляет свой функционал. На черновом варианте все работало:

```
ignore_list = ['12345678']

from_id = 12345678

if from_id not in ignore_list:
    print('hello')
elif from_id in ignore_list:
    print('you are in blacklist')
#на выводе все корректно: you are in blacklist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы в каком формате в списке храните идентификаторы пользователей? VK Api возвращает целочисленное значение.
Не знаю, как Вы проверяли, но в коде ниже (где в выводе "все корректно") программа выводит hello, т.к. типы данных различаются.

Comment: Черт. Точно. Настолько глупо вышло, что мне сейчас стало очень стыдно, спасибо огромное.